# server side button click event not firing inside UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a user control which is using updatepanel. when the page first loads the button click is working fine and the is shown in a DIV...when i search again and hit the button, click event is not firing, even the page load event is also not firing. I am using google geocoding for find the nearest stores when you type postcode. I suspect it is with javascript or page validation which is not letting the button to fire click event. here is my code.

## ASPX PAGE

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ClickAndCollect.ascx.cs"
      Inherits="ConLib_Custom_ClickAndCollect" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CommerceBuilder.Web" Namespace="CommerceBuilder.Web.UI.WebControls"
      TagPrefix="cb" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/ClickAndCollectGeoCoding.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ClickAndCollectUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="ClickAndCollectPanelTitle">
            Click and Collect
            <p>
                  Your order will be available to collect in store in 24 - 72 hours
                  <br />
                  We will email you as soon as your order is ready for collection
            </p>
        </div>
         <div class="errorPostcodeSummaryDiv">
              <asp:Label ID="errorPostcodeSummary" Text="" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="errorPostcodeSummary">
              </asp:Label>
         </div>        
        <div class="ClickAndCollectContainer">
                <div class="ClickAndCollectContents">
                    <div class="ClickAndCollectHeader">
                        <asp:Label ID="ClickAndCollectDesc" runat="server" Text="Find your nearest store" CssClass="ClickAndCollectDesc"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ClickAndCollectTextBox" runat="server" Text="" ToolTip="Enter Your Postcode" CssClass="ClickAndCollectTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
                        <ajax:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="ClickAndCollectTextWatermark" runat="server" TargetControlID="ClickAndCollectTextBox" WatermarkText="Postcode or Town" WatermarkCssClass="watermark"></ajax:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>

                        <asp:Button ID="ClickAndCollectSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="ClickAndCollectSubmit" Text="Find Stores" onClick= "ClickAndCollectSubmit_Click"/>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ClickAndCollectTextBoxValidator" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="OPC"
                                ControlToValidate = "ClickAndCollectTextBox" CssClass="ClickAndCollectValidatorError"
                                ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid address to search for the nearest stores." Text="*">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ClickAndCollectResult">
                        <asp:Panel ID="ClickAndCollectResultPanel" Visible="false" CssClass="ClickAndCollectResult"
                            runat="server">
                            <div class="ClickAndCollectResultHeader">
                                Choose your nearest store
                            </div>
                            <div class="ClickAndCollectResultTable">
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="StoresRadioList" Visible="false" runat="server" ToolTip="Choose your nearest store" CssClass="ClickAndCollectResultRadios" ValidationGroup="OPC" onselectedindexchanged="StoresRadioList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StoresRadioValidator" runat="server"  ControlToValidate = "StoresRadioList"  Text ="*" CssClass="ClickAndCollectValidatorError" ErrorMessage = "Please choose one store for your delivery.">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="selectedAddress">
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="selectedStore" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="latValue" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="lanValue" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="statusCode" runat="server"/>
                </div>
            </div>
         </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

## JS File

```
var address;
var region;

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
      if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
            AttachEventAfterPostback();
      }
}

function AttachEventAfterPostback() {
      $(document).ready(function () {
            address = $('.ClickAndCollectTextBox').val();
            if (address.length != 0) {
                  checkAddress(address);
                  getLatLong(address, region);

            }
            $('.ClickAndCollectTextBox').on('blur', function () {
                  address = $('.ClickAndCollectTextBox').val();
                  if (address.length != 0) {
                        checkAddress(address);
                        getLatLong(address, region);
                  }
            });
      });
}

function getLatLong(address, region) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var result = "";
            geocoder.geocode({
                  'address': address,
                  'region': region
            }, function (results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        $("[id$='statusCode']").val("OK");
                        $("[id$='latValue']").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                        $("[id$='lanValue']").val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                        //                        if (typeof (callback) == "function") {
                        //                              callback();
                        //                        }
                  } else {
                        $("[id$='statusCode']").val("ZERO_RESULTS");
                        $("[id$='latValue']").val("0");
                        $("[id$='lanValue']").val("0");
                  }
            });
      }

AttachEventAfterPostback();

function checkAddress(inputAddress) {
      switch (inputAddress.toUpperCase()) {
            //some code
      }
}
```

## *EDIT***

"What i am doing is as soon as user enters postcode and textbox losses focus, i am calling geocode to get LAT and LNG values ready in hidden fields. as soon as user clicks, click events fire on server and shows the result using RadiobuttonList. as soon user select one radio, one div shows up with the details of the store they selected. NOW lets say if they dont select one radio and try to enter diff postcode, then button click not working. BUT if they select one radio and then try diff postcode, button click works fine..

anyone have any idea why this is happening...

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with a developer console (F12 in many browsers)?  Also, are you getting an error message you can give us?

Comment: no error messages in console. I have tried this in chrome and whenever i put alert using jquery on that button, its showing me a alert window BUT somehow it is not firing server side button click event..

Answer (score 1):

you are attaching the event in the wrong manner.

The update panel makes a partial page postback and will never be in document ready until you manually refresh the page.

remove the `AttachEventAfterPostback` and write your code in pageLoad function like this which wil auto rebind every thing after every partial postback

```
function pageLoad(sender,args){
    address = $('.ClickAndCollectTextBox').val();
    if (address.length != 0) {
       checkAddress(address);
       getLatLong(address, region);

    }
    $('.ClickAndCollectTextBox').on('blur', function () {
       address = $('.ClickAndCollectTextBox').val();
          if (address.length != 0) {
              checkAddress(address);
              getLatLong(address, region);
          }
       });
}
```

Comment: this is good one... i have made the changes accordingly BUT still it does not work

Comment: Have you tried console logging the info line by line on blur event after pageload. And debug which line is causing the error..

Comment: yes, i have tried that.. i was logging Lat, Lng everytime textbox losses focus and it returns with status OK with values. I am not sure why this is happening..

Comment: see my edits please... i think it has to do with the radio button which populates after the button click